# Subsequence Weighting

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
**Problem: -----------------
==========================================
```

A subsequence of a sequence is a sequence which is obtained by deleting zero or more elements from the sequence. You are given a sequence A in which every element is a pair of integers  i.e  A = [(a1, w1), (a2, w2),..., (aN, wN)].For a subseqence B = [(b1, v1), (b2, v2), ...., (bM, vM)] of the given sequence : 
We call it increasing if for every i (1 <= i < M ) , bi < bi+1.Weight(B) = v1 + v2 + ... + vM.

```
    Task:
    Given a sequence, output the maximum weight formed by an increasing subsequence.

    Input:
    The first line of input contains a single integer T. T test-cases follow. The first line of each test-case contains an integer N. The next line contains a1, a2 ,... , aN separated by a single space. The next line contains w1, w2, ..., wN separated by a single space.

    Output:
    For each test-case output a single integer: The maximum weight of increasing subsequences of the given sequence.

    Constraints:
    1 <= T <= 5
    1 <= N <= 150000
    1 <= ai <= 109, where i ∈ [1..N]
    1 <= wi <= 109, where i ∈ [1..N]

    Sample Input:

    2  
    4  
    1 2 3 4  
    10 20 30 40  
    8  
    1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4  
    10 20 30 40 15 15 15 50

    Sample Output:

    100  
    110

    Explanation:
    In the first sequence, the maximum size increasing subsequence is 4, and there's only one of them. We choose B = [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 40)], and we have Weight(B) = 100.

    In the second sequence, the maximum size increasing subsequence is still 4, but there are now 5 possible subsequences:

    1 2 3 4  
    10 20 30 40

    1 2 3 4  
    10 20 30 50

    1 2 3 4  
    10 20 15 50

    1 2 3 4  
    10 15 15 50

    1 2 3 4  
    15 15 15 50

    Of those, the one with the greatest weight is B = [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 50)], with Weight(B) = 110.

    Please note that this is not the maximum weight generated from picking the highest value element of each index. That value, 115, comes from [(1, 15), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 50)], which is not a valid subsequence because it cannot be created by only deleting elements in the original sequence.**
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = scanner.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Input> testInput = new ArrayList<Input>(T);

        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            Input input = new Input();
            input.N = scanner.nextInt();

            input.value = new int[input.N];
            input.weight = new int[input.N];

            for (int j = 0; j < input.N; j++) {
                input.value[j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < input.N; j++) {
                input.weight[j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }

            testInput.add(input);
        }

        int maxSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            maxSum = findMaxSubsequenceSum(testInput.get(i));
            System.out.println(maxSum);
        }
    }

    private static int findMaxSubsequenceSum(Input input) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = input.getInputMap();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(map.values());
        int[] index = new int[map.size()];
        Arrays.fill(index, 0);
        int maxSum = getMaxSumInSequence(lists, index);
        return maxSum;
    }

    private static int getMaxSumInSequence(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists, int index[]) {
        int result = 0;
        int maxSum = 0;
        boolean indexUpdate = true;
        int maxListLength = lists.get(0).size();

        while (isValidSequence(index) && indexUpdate) {
            result = addAllListItem(lists, index);
            if (maxSum < result) {
                maxSum = result;
            }
            indexUpdate = updateIndex(maxListLength, index);
        }
        return maxSum;
    }

    private static int addAllListItem(List<ArrayList<Integer>> lists, int index[]) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            result += lists.get(i).get(index[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isValidSequence(int index[]) {
        int i = index[0];
        boolean result = false;

        for (int l = 1; l < index.length; l++) {
            if (i <= index[l]) {
                result = true;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }
            i = index[l];
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean updateIndex(int maxIndex, int index[]) {
        boolean result = false;

        if (index[0] == maxIndex - 1) {
            return result;
        }

        int indexSize = index.length - 1;
        if (index[0] == index[indexSize]) {
            index[indexSize]++;
            result = true;
        } else {
            for (int i = indexSize; i > 0; i--) {
                int indexValue = index[i];
                if (indexValue > index[i - 1]) {
                    index[i - 1]++;
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static class Input {
        public int N;
        public int[] value;
        public int[] weight;

        public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> getInputMap() {
            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int key = value[i];
                int item = weight[i];

                if (map.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(key))) {
                    map.get(Integer.valueOf(key)).add(item);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    list.add(new Integer(item));
                    map.put(new Integer(key), list);
                }
            }
            return map;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Does not work for :- 1 4 3 4  
10 20 30 40. Answer should be 80 but is coming as 60 from this solution.